# Can't install anaconda on Ubuntu 20.04. ~/anaconda3 folder is not created?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, anaconda

I downloaded the installer from here:

https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual/download-success

I then go to my downloads folder and run

`sudo bash  Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh`

I scroll through the license and  try to install at the default /root/anaconda3 without changing anything. It seems to go OK. It asks if I want to do conda init, I say yes, and this is the result:

```
no change     /root/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /root/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /root/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /root/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /root/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /root/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /root/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /root/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /root/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /root/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified      /root/.bashrc
```

However as far as I can tell .bashrc is not actually changed at all. There is no mention of conda or anaconda anywhere. Also, the ~/anaconda3 folder does not exist, so if I do any conda commands in terminal, it obviously fails ( `conda: command not found`). By using `sudo -i` and going to /root/ I can see that /root/anaconda3 exists but from what I understand, these are binaries and not where your conda path should go to, right?  There is a /root/anaconda3/bin/conda executable if I put something like

`export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:"$PATH"`

or

`export PATH=/root/anaconda/bin:"$PATH"`

I still get nada when I try to run a conda command, command is still not found. (And yes I source the .bashrc or open a new terminal window).

I also tried installing anaconda to other places like ~/temp/anaconda3 just to see what happened. The installer didn't make anything there either.

I'm a bit lost here, what can I do?

Comment: You should not install as root... I would undo the installation by removing `/root/anaconda3` and removing the conda part of `/root/.bashrc`. Then install anaconda with `bash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh` (not as root).

Comment: @jakub That seems to have done it, glad it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should not install as root... I would undo the installation by removing `/root/anaconda3` and removing the conda part of `/root/.bashrc`. Then install anaconda with `bash Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh` (not as root).

-- [comment](/questions/68627824/#comment121284648_68627824) by [jakub](/users/5666087/jakub)